# Displaying Div's based on URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m new to Javascript and I’m having trouble displaying and hiding some divs based on url’s.

I have 4 divs that need to be shown depending on the url.
The 4 divs are:

**Div 1**

```
<body onload="callOnPageLoad1()”>
<div id="homeName" style="display:block"><h5>HOME</h5></div>
```

and needs to be displayed only when at:

```
http://www.fitzofdesign.com/
```

**Div 2**

```
<body onload="callOnPageLoad2()”>
<div id="profilesName" style="display:block"><h5>PROFILES</h5></div>
```

and needs to be displayed only when at:

```
http://www.fitzofdesign.com/?category=Profiles
```

**Div 3**

```
<body onload="callOnPageLoad3()”>
<div id="retailName" style="display:block"><h5>RETAIL</h5></div>
```

and needs to be displayed only when at:

```
http://www.fitzofdesign.com/?category=Retail
```

**Div 4**

```
<body onload="callOnPageLoad4()”>
<div id="blogName" style="display:block"><h5>BLOG</h5></div>
```

and needs to be displayed only when at:

```
http://www.fitzofdesign.com/?category=Blog
```

The JS I’m using is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callOnPageLoad1()
{
var url = window.location.href;
if(url == "http://www.fitzofdesign.com/")
{
document.getElementById('homeName').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('profilesNamed').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('retailName').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('blogName').style.display = 'none';
}
else {
document.getElementById('homeName').style.display = 'none';
}
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function callOnPageLoad2()
{
var url = window.location.href;
if(url == "http://www.fitzofdesign.com/?category=Profiles")
{
document.getElementById('homeName').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('profilesNamed').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('retailName').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('blogName').style.display = 'none';
}
else {
document.getElementById('profilesNamed').style.display = 'none';
}
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function callOnPageLoad3()
{
var url = window.location.href;
if(url == "http://www.fitzofdesign.com/?category=Retail")
{
document.getElementById('homeName').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('profilesNamed').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('retailName').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('blogName').style.display = 'none';
}
else {
document.getElementById('retailName').style.display = 'none';
}
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function callOnPageLoad4()
{
var url = window.location.href;
if(url == "http://www.fitzofdesign.com/?category=Blog")
{
document.getElementById('homeName').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('profilesNamed').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('retailName').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('blogName').style.display = 'block';
}
else {
document.getElementById('blogName').style.display = 'none';
}
}
</script>
```

At present the only time this is **working** correctly is when I’m at:

```
http://www.fitzofdesign.com/
```

because Div 1 appears and the other 3 Divs are hidden.

This is **not working** when I’m at:

```
http://www.fitzofdesign.com/?category=Profiles
http://www.fitzofdesign.com/?category=Retail
http://www.fitzofdesign.com/?category=Blog
```

because Div 2, 3 & 4 are all incorrectly displaying for each URL.

I hope this makes sense.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks Rowan

Comment: URL won't look like `http://www.fitzofdesign.com/?category=Retail`. They are more likely to look like `http://www.fitzofdesign.com?category=Retail`. Double check the URLs, and make sure your URL's are correct.

Comment: I just did an echo curPageURL(); to be certain and the URLs are correct unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine all those functions into something like:

```
var url = window.location.href;
if(url == "http://www.fitzofdesign.com/")
{
    document.getElementById('homeName').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('profilesNamed').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('retailName').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('blogName').style.display = 'none';
} 
else if(url == "http://www.fitzofdesign.com/?category=Profiles")
{
    document.getElementById('homeName').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('profilesNamed').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('retailName').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('blogName').style.display = 'none';
}
```

And you need to make sure this check is called after everything loads, so put inside something like a jquery document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href
    // rest of the code
}
```

Also, you might want to change the checks from:

```
url == "http://www.fitzofdesign.com/?category=Profiles"
```

to

```
url.indexOf("category=Profiles") > -1
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Firstly hide all the divs.
On window.onLoad event, fetch the querystring value and use that to display the appropriate div.

Below is the code snippet to extract the querystring  category value.

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok first, you don't need to put each of those in their own script tags. Keep them together.

Second, save stuff you repeat in JS as variables for performance and cleaner code:

```
var url = window.location.href,
fitz = "http://www.fitzofdesign.com/"
home = document.getElementById('homeName'),
profile = document.getElementById('profilesNamed'),
retail = document.getElementById('retailName').style.display,
blog = document.getElementById('blogName').style.display;
```

Third, you can check variables against each other:

```
if( url == fitz ) {
    home.style.display = 'block';
    profile.style.display = 'none';
    retail.style.display = 'none';
    blog.style.display = 'none';
}
else if ( url == fitz + "?category=Profiles" ) {
    home.style.display = 'none';
    profile.style.display = 'block';
    retail.style.display = 'none';
    blog.style.display = 'none';
}
else if ( url == fitz + "?category=Profiles" ) {
    // etc.
}
```

Finally, you need to create an event listener that will determine when a click or some other user behavior occurs. That should trigger this function each time.

Look up [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)